# How to generate random numbers and compare them with token inputs?

Tags: python

So i'm trying to make a function def number_guess(num): in order to generate some random integers and compare them with certain inputs() and print some statements.

For ex if i input:

```
32 45 48 80
```

My target output is

```
32 is too low. Random number was 80.
45 is too high. Random number was 30.
48 is correct!
80 is too low. Random number was 97.
```

We are also using the seed value 900, which will cause the computer to choose the same random number every time the program runs.

So far my code is:

```
# TODO: Import the random module
import random

def number_guess(num):
    # TODO: Get a random number between 1-100

    random.randint(1,100)

    # TODO: Read numbers and compare to random number

    for token in tokens:
        if token < randint:
            print('{} is too low. Random number was {}.'.format(user_input[0], randint))
        elif token > randint:
            print('{} is too high. Random number was {}.'.format(user_input[1], randint))
        elif token == randint:
            print('{} is correct!'.format(randint))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Use the seed 900 to get the same pseudo random numbers every time
    random.seed(900)

    # Convert the string tokens into integers
    user_input = input()
    tokens = user_input.split()
    for token in tokens:
        num = int(token)
        number_guess(num)
```

I tried:
def number_guess(num):
        # TODO: Get a random number between 1-100

```
    randint = ['']
    random.randint(1,100)

    # TODO: Read numbers and compare to random number

    for num in tokens:
        if token < randint:
            print('{} is too low. Random number was {}.'.format(num[0], randint))
        elif token > randint:
            print('{} is too high. Random number was {}.'.format(num[1], randint))
        elif token == randint:
            print('{} is correct!'.format(randint))
```

But i'm not really understanding the format and how the functions for this should work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: randint = random.randint(1,100)

Answer (score 1):

You should replace this:

```
randint = ['']
random.randint(1,100)
```

with this:

```
randint = random.randint(1,100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your `random.randint()` call to memory.

Use a variable like `randint = random.randint()`, since it will work in your code now.

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues with your code, the chief of which was that you did not do anything with the random number you generated, and tried accessing it through the name `randint`, which would cause an "undefined name" exception.

A somewhat simplified version of you code, that will also work, would look like this:

```
import random

tokens = [32, 45, 48, 80]

def number_guess():
    secret = random.randint(1,100)
    for token in tokens:
        if token < secret:
            print('{} is too low. Random number was {}.'.format(token, secret))
        elif token > secret:
            print('{} is too high. Random number was {}.'.format(token, secret))
        elif token == secret:
            print('{} is correct!'.format(secret))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Use the seed 900 to get the same pseudo random numbers every time
    random.seed(900)
    number_guess()
```

I removed the user input part, irrelevant parameters, and an extraneous loop, and now you get feedback on all the tested tokens:

```
32 is too low. Random number was 80.
45 is too low. Random number was 80.
48 is too low. Random number was 80.
80 is correct!
```

Comment: what if i dont want a defined list of tokens, just user entered input integers?

Comment: @yeobub In that case you could do `tokens = [input1, input2, input3, input4]` where each of those variables were promoted for earlier.

Comment: @yeobub - you already had code for that in your question, you just used the retrieved list of tokens incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the code that works for me**

```
# TODO: Import the random module
import random

def number_guess(num):
    # TODO: Get a random number between 1-100
    rand_num = random.randint(1,100)
    # TODO: Read numbers and compare to random number
    if num < rand_num:
        print('{} is too low. Random number was {}.'.format(num, rand_num))
    elif num > rand_num:
        print('{} is too high. Random number was {}.'.format(num, rand_num))
    else:
        print(rand_num,"is correct!")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Use the seed 900 to get the same pseudo random numbers every time
    random.seed(900)
    
    # Convert the string tokens into integers
    user_input = input()
    tokens = user_input.split()
    for token in tokens:
        num = int(token)
        number_guess(num)
```